# Addition and multiplication of two input values does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple `onclick()` function using `getElementById` to get values from an input group but one of my local variables seems to not work within only one other local variable.

```
    function hRadOpRec() {
    var hgt = document.getElementById("oRecHgt").value;
    var bot = document.getElementById("oRecBot").value;
    var wPer = ((2 * hgt) + bot);
    var cSec = (hgt * bot);
    var hRad = (cSec / wPer);
    return document.getElementById("hRORec").value = hRad;
    }

 <div class="col-md-3 collapse" id="hRadOpRec">
  <h4>Açık Dikdörtgen Kanal Hidrolik Yarıçap</h4>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Sıvı Yüksekliği (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="oRecHgt">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Taban Genişliği (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="oRecBot">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="hRadOpRec()">Hesapla</button>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Hidrolik Yarıçap (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly id="hRORec">
  </div> 
 </div>
```

I've tried debugging it, and the variable `bot` when put in the `wPer` variable seems to just mess everything up. When I remove bot from `wPer` it works just as it should. Putting `bot` in other variables also doesn't cause any problems. For example when `hgt` and `bot` are 10 the function should return `100/30` but instead it returns `0.04975124378109453`. When I remove `bot` from `wPer`, for the same values the function returns `100/20` as it should.

Comment: `console.log()` both  `hgt` and `bot` and check of values are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing is `parseInt()` function

Because `hgt` and `bot` are string, when you are computing `wPer` and `cSec`, a concatenation also occurs. Let suppose that the user types in `10` and `10` respectively for the first and second input.

- wPer: `((2 * hgt) + bot) = ((2*"10")+"20") = 20 + "20" = 2020`. The times operator `*` will perform a multiplication even when it is two strings that are operands because they will be parsed whereas the `+` operator will perform a concatenation when one of the operand is a string.
- cSec: `(hgt * bot) = ("10"*"10") = 100`, a normal multiplication, though both operands are strings
- `100/1020` will be the output of your function.

Below is what you want to do, using `parseInt()`

```js
function hRadOpRec() {
    var hgt = parseInt(document.getElementById("oRecHgt").value);
    var bot = parseInt(document.getElementById("oRecBot").value);
    var wPer = ((2 * hgt) + bot);
    var cSec = (hgt * bot);
    var hRad = (cSec / wPer);
    return document.getElementById("hRORec").value= hRad;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-3 collapse" id="hRadOpRec">
  <h4>Açık Dikdörtgen Kanal Hidrolik Yarıçap</h4>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Sıvı Yüksekliği (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="oRecHgt">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Taban Genişliği (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="oRecBot">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="hRadOpRec()">Hesapla</button>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Hidrolik Yarıçap (m)</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly id="hRORec">
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. Can you tell me why this wasn't an issue with multiplication and division?

Comment: @yanabeca, I updated my answer to explain what was happening

Comment: Thank you so very much, that's really helpful.